# converting .live() to .on() or .click() functions jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm currently following a tutorial that uses an old version of jQuery to create an mvc with a built in todo list using ajax calls. The original code went as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o) {
        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
        {
            $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="'+o[i].id+'" href="#">X</a></div>');
        }

        $('.del').live('click', function() {
            delItem = $(this);
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');
            $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': id}, function(o) {
                delItem.parent().remove();
            }, 'json');
            return false;
        });
    }, 'json');

    $('#randomInsert').submit(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.post(url, data, function(o) {
            $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o.text + '<a class="del" rel="'+ o.id +'" href="#">X</a></div>');        
        }, 'json');
            return false;
    });
});
```

When I updated the jQuery version it threw a hissy fit and wouldn't work so I looked up the error and it didn't like up the `.live()` function and so a suggestion was to use `.on()`

And so I changed the `.live` into

```
$(document).on("click", ".del", function()
```

Now the code does delete from the database but doesn't update until the page is refreshed . . . am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try `$('.del').on('click', function()`

Comment: Can we see the full updated coded? What do you mean "doesn't update until the page is refreshed"? Your `.on()` example looks accurate to me, although you don't probably want it to bubble up all the way to `document`... the containing parent will work.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".del", function() {...` is the correct replacement for `$(".del").live("click", function() {...` (though rather than `document` it is better to use a parent element closer to the elements in question, e.g., `$('#listInserts').on("click", ".del", function() {...`).

Comment: Throw a breakpoint at the line where it should remove the element from the DOM and make sure that it's actually pointing at something.

Comment: You don't actually need event delegation here.

Comment: @KevinB `.del` elements are appended in the other handler he posted, so delegation would be necessary for those to work.

Comment: what was meant by wont disappear unless the page is reloaded is that the original .del element when clicked the item was deleted from the database and the updated information should show that it has been deleted.

Comment: I suspect the issue has nothing to do with how he is binding the event. It sounds like the ajax request is actually failing, resulting in the element not being removed. Delegating the event in the success of the $.get should be fine, as that only gets executed once. sure, it's later than it needs to be, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: so that would mean that changing .on to .live or any other function should not impact on the problem im having as these are shown from the  xhrgetlisting however all i have done is updated jquery to which .on is no longer included and so changed it to .live ?? i knw i can run both jquery versions or just put refesh on the end but i dont want to cheat im doing this to learn

Comment: that would be my guess, yes. If the record is getting deleted from the database, but the row isn't being removed, then your post is resulting in the error callback rather than success. Note however there's a potential bug here. you need to put `var` before `delItem = $(this)`

Comment: and the items are getting deleted from the database just not the page untill refresh

Comment: are there anyways to find out if i am getting an error rather than success ?

Comment: Yes, add the error callback to it. `$.post(...).fail(function(a,b,c){ alert(c) });` for jQuery < 1.5, replace `fail` with `error`

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the event to the `document`.  So you do not need to do this more than once, and the elements in question do not need to be present when you bind the event.  Move the `on` syntax outside of the ajax callback, inside the document ready.

```
$(function(){
    $('#listInserts').on("click", ".del", function() {

    });

})
```

Other option is to leave it inside the callback, and modify your code to be:

```
$.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o) {
    $('.del').on('click',function(){
    });

});
```

**NOTE**: As suggested below in the comment, the first option would be more suitable in this case since the `.del` elements are added in the `subtmit`, unless you want to bind the click event from there as well.

Comment: Arguably the `.live` call never should have been in there either.

Comment: It should be moved outside and stick with the delegated method because the `.submit()` handler also adds `.del` elements.

Comment: see @nnnnnn comments on question regarding `.on()` binding not to document.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - what? the on() method does bind to the document in the first code block in my answer, in the second it does not

Comment: The desire is to NOT bind to document if an identifiable parent closer is present as this allows a shorter DOM stack for the attached event handler.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - you are right, it is better to bind to a closer parent.  I've adjusted my answer.  I see you posted an answer too, but binding to the document??

Answer (score 0):

- Move event handler for `.del` outside callback function
- Change to reuse cached `delItem`
- Remove `delItem` from global scope

Modified code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".del", function () {
        var delItem = $(this);
        var id = delItem.attr('rel');
        $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {
            'id': id
        }, function (o) {
            delItem.parent().remove();
        }, 'json');
    });
    $.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function (o) {
        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o[i].id + '" href="#">X</a></div>');
        }
    }, 'json');
    $('#randomInsert').submit(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(url, data, function (o) {
            $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o.text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o.id + '" href="#">X</a></div>');
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```

EDIT Revised to only hit the DOM once on the insert, bind to the wrapper for the '`on()` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listInserts').on("click", ".del", function () {
        var delItem = $(this);
        var id = delItem.attr('rel');
        $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {
            'id': id
        }, function (o) {
            delItem.parent().remove();
        }, 'json');
    });

    $.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function (o) {
        var newlinks = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            newlinks = newlinks + '<div>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o[i].id + '" href="#">X</a></div>';
        }
        $('#listInserts').append(newlinks);
    }, 'json');

    $('#randomInsert').submit(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(url, data, function (o) {
            $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o.text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o.id + '" href="#">X</a></div>');
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would re-write the sample code. I've commented where I changed things.

```
$(function() {
    var $listInserts = $('#listInserts'); // Store the element once so we don't have to do it again

    // Function for re-usability
    function addToList (text, id) {
        $listInserts.append('<div>' + text + '<a class="del" rel="'+id+'" href="#">X</a></div>');
    }

    // Here I'm assuming that $('#listInserts') is a container for all those .del elements.
    // If you use .on() on a containing element try to keep as close to those elements as you can.
    // Keeping it close keeps the events from having to bubble up through every parent element on the page.
    $listInserts.on('click', '.del', function(e) {
        var $delItem = $(this);

        e.preventDefault(); // Stops the normal link behavior. Sort of like 'return false;' would do.

        $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': this.id}, function(o) {
                $delItem.parent().remove();
            }, 'json');
    });

    $.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o) {

        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
        {
            addToList(o[i].text, o[i].id);
        }
    }, 'json');

    // Changed to .on()
    $('#randomInsert').on('submit', function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        e.preventDefault();

        $.post(url, data, function(o) {
            addToList(o.text, o.id);
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution for this jquery script with the latest lib:

```
$(function() {

$('#listInserts').on('click', '.del', function() {
    var delItem = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': id}, function() {
        delItem.parent().remove();
    });
});

$.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o) {
    for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o[i].text + ' <a class="del" rel="' + o[i].id + '" href="#">elimina</a></div>');
    }
}, 'json'); // JSON = JavaScript Object Notation

$('#randomInsert').submit(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post(url, data, function(o) {
        $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o.text + ' <a class="del" rel="' + o.id + '" href="#">elimina</a></div>');
    }, 'json');
    return false;
});});
```

Hope this help.